# Create pandas data frame column based on strings from two other columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
boat_type   boat_type_2
Not Known   Not Known
Not Known   kayak
ship        Not Known
Not Known   Not Known
ship        Not Known
```

And I want to create a third columns `boat_type_final` that should look like this:

```
boat_type   boat_type_2  boat_type_final
Not Known   Not Known    cruise
Not Known   kayak        kayak
ship        Not Known    ship  
Not Known   Not Known    cruise
ship        Not Known    ship
```

So basically if 'Not Known' is present in both`boat_type` and `boat_type_2`, then the value should be 'cruise'. But if there is a string other than 'Not Known' in the first two columns, then `boat_type_final` should be filled with that string, either 'kayak' or 'ship'.

What's the most elegant way to do this? I've seen several options such as `where`, creating a function, and/or logic, and I'd like to know what a true pythonista would do.

Here's my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = [{'boat_type': 'Not Known', 'boat_type_2': 'Not Known'},
    {'boat_type': 'Not Known',  'boat_type_2': 'kayak'},
    {'boat_type': 'ship',  'boat_type_2': 'Not Known'},
    {'boat_type': 'Not Known',  'boat_type_2': 'Not Known'},
    {'boat_type': 'ship',  'boat_type_2': 'Not Known'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data
df['phone_type_final'] = np.where(df.phone_type.str.contains('Not'))...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
df['boat_type_final'] = (df.replace('Not Known',np.nan)
                           .ffill(axis=1)
                           .iloc[:, -1]
                           .fillna('cruise'))
print (df)
   boat_type boat_type_2 boat_type_final
0  Not Known   Not Known          cruise
1  Not Known       kayak           kayak
2       ship   Not Known            ship
3  Not Known   Not Known          cruise
4       ship   Not Known            ship
```

**Explanation**:

First [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) `Not Known` to missing values:

```
print (df.replace('Not Known',np.nan))
  boat_type boat_type_2
0       NaN         NaN
1       NaN       kayak
2      ship         NaN
3       NaN         NaN
4      ship         NaN
```

Then replace `NaN`s by forward filling per rows:

```
print (df.replace('Not Known',np.nan).ffill(axis=1))
  boat_type boat_type_2
0       NaN         NaN
1       NaN       kayak
2      ship        ship
3       NaN         NaN
4      ship        ship
```

Select last column by position by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
print (df.replace('Not Known',np.nan).ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1])
0      NaN
1    kayak
2     ship
3      NaN
4     ship
Name: boat_type_2, dtype: object
```

And if possible `NaN`s add [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
print (df.replace('Not Known',np.nan).ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1].fillna('cruise'))
0    cruise
1     kayak
2      ship
3    cruise
4      ship
Name: boat_type_2, dtype: object
```

---

Another solution if only a few columns is use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
m1 = df['boat_type'] == 'ship'
m2 = df['boat_type_2'] == 'kayak'

df['boat_type_final'] = np.select([m1, m2], ['ship','kayak'], default='cruise')
print (df)
   boat_type boat_type_2 boat_type_final
0  Not Known   Not Known          cruise
1  Not Known       kayak           kayak
2       ship   Not Known            ship
3  Not Known   Not Known          cruise
4       ship   Not Known            ship
```

Comment: Can you explain a little about how/why that works? Particularly this part: `.ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1]`

Comment: @bzier - Sure, give me a sec.

Comment: @bzier - Answer was modified.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to define your function where you have the mappings:

```
def my_func(row):
    if row['boat_type']!='Not Known':
        return row['boat_type']
    elif row['boat_type_2']!='Not Known':
        return row['boat_type_2']
    else: 
        return 'cruise'
```

[Note: you did not mention what should happen when neither of columns is 'Not Known'.]

Then simply apply the function:

```
df.loc[:,'boat_type_final'] = df.apply(my_func, axis=1)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   boat_type boat_type_2 boat_type_final
0  Not Known   Not Known          cruise
1  Not Known       kayak           kayak
2       ship   Not Known            ship
3  Not Known   Not Known          cruise
4       ship   Not Known            ship
```